# Controlling margins when making a PDF using Playwright

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, chromium, playwright, css-print

When making a PDF from a headless chrome Playwright session (code below) I get the PDF on the left, whereas if I make it through the save to pdf in chrome, I get the second output.

[image]

I have set the margins explicitly and used `preferCSSPageSize: true` and both give the same (left) outcome.

**How would I get Playwright to give me the same output as chrome does from the print dialog?**

An example of the [files being printed is here](https://gist.github.com/notionparallax/dfd37e51e9dee308ee39193ed765a636). (In real life, they're all slightly different to account for the spine width.)

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

const directoryPath = "outside";

(async () => {
  const filesToPrint = getFilesToPrintList(directoryPath);
  filesToPrint.forEach((f, i) => console.log(i, f));
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true });
  const context = await browser.newContext();

  for (let i = 0; i < filesToPrint.length; i++) {
    const htmlFilename = path.join(directoryPath, filesToPrint[i]);
    const pdfFilename = makePDFfilename(htmlFilename);
    console.log("[html file]", htmlFilename);
    console.log("[pdf file]", pdfFilename);
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto(
      "file:///" + path.resolve(htmlFilename),
      (waitUntil = "networkidle")
    );
    const options = {
      path: pdfFilename,
      pageRanges: "1",
      preferCSSPageSize: true,
    };
    console.log(
      `\n\nAbout to print:\n  ${pdfFilename}\n`,
      `with:\n${JSON.stringify(options, null, 2)}`
    );
    await page.pdf(options);
  }
  await browser.close();
  console.log("done");
})();

function makePDFfilename(htmlFilename) {
  const parts = htmlFilename.split(/[\\\._]/);
  const pdfFilename = path.join(
    directoryPath,
    `Experimental_${parts[1]}_${parts[2]}.pdf`
  );
  return pdfFilename;
}

function getFilesToPrintList(directoryPath) {
  let theFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(directoryPath)
    .filter((f) => f.includes("fp_") && f.includes(".html"));
  return theFiles;
}
```

Comment: I think the issue could be solved on v1.12.3. I had a similar problem, but then I realised I was using an old version of playwright. With the last version as in july 2021, the problem disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your issue:

I used a different background image URL (online) with your HTML page, see [**test.html**](https://gist.github.com/iamAzeem/844c96f4146694e79698e1f650ca4716) gist.

Apparently, a number of options are the defaults. See [`page.pdf()`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.3.0&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pagepdfoptions).

Also, added `browser.newContext()` and `browser.close()`.

Here's the minimal working NodeJS code:

**generate-pdf.js**

```js
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

(async () => {
    const htmlFilename = "file:///<file-path>/test.html";
    console.log("[webpage]", htmlFilename);

    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto(htmlFilename);

    const pdfFilename = "./test.pdf";
    console.log("[pdf file]", pdfFilename);

    const options = {
      path: pdfFilename,
      pageRanges: "1",
      preferCSSPageSize: true
    };

    console.log(
      `\n\nAbout to print:\n  ${pdfFilename}\n`,
      `with:\n${JSON.stringify(options, null, 2)}`
    );

    await page.pdf(options);
    await browser.close();

    console.log("done");
})();
```

Console Output:

```sh
$ node generate-pdf.js
[webpage] file:///<file-path>/test.html
[pdf file] ./test.pdf


About to print:
  ./test.pdf
 with:
{
  "path": "./test.pdf",
  "pageRanges": "1",
  "preferCSSPageSize": true
}
done
```

Snapshot of PDF (**test.pdf**):

[image: test.pdf]

You might want to test this separately and see if it works for your use-case.

Comment: I've tried integrating your modifications, but I still get the margin. I've updated the code in the question to reflect this.
Am I missing something significant? (Using Playwright 1.3.0, Chromium 86.0.4217.0)

Comment: @Ben: Not really sure. There might be some environment-related issues. I'm using Chromimum 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Playwright version is the same 1.3.0.

Comment: @Ben: Instead of integration, can you please try to run my code?

Comment: running your code directly also produces a pdf with margins, sadly

Comment: @Ben: Right. Maybe, you need to test on a different machine.